# how to create a list of functions in R?

Tags: r

I have a function of two parameters, and from that I'd like
to create a list of functions in one parameter, like this:

```
flist <- lapply(c(1,2), function(x) { function(y) x + y })
```

This is intended to create a list of two functions, the first
of which adds one to its input; the second of which adds two
to its input.  But it doesn't work:

```
> flist[[1]](3)
[1] 5
> flist[[2]](3)
[1] 5
```

Both of the functions in the list add two to their input.
I have workarounds, but they are ugly, and I'd like to understand
what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481404/how-to-create-a-vector-of-functions

Comment: Thanks!  I now have `{ force(x); function(y) x + y }` instead of just `{ function(y) x + y }`, and I get what I want.