# Define piecewise linear function in R, call function from a list of functions

Tags: r, piecewise

I have been looking for a solution for a long time but still didn't get it to work. I'm very grateful for every helpful suggestion!

I am trying to define a piecewise linear function in R, this means, I want to define a function that has different linear expressions on different intervals. Those intervals depend on data points (and the number of these data points) given in xWerte and yWerte, so the number of cutting points and different function rules aren't fix (that's why I'm trying this crap with for loops and not with an ifelse-construction...)

What I have been trying so far is defining the cuts (cutting points of the intervals) and the values = function rules on each of these intervals.
I write down the code to enable you to understand what I've done, although it seems to me that this part is working and my question doesn't concern this part of my code...

```
# cuts contains the points where the function rule changes, this works fine    
cuts <- c(xWerte[2])
for(i in 3:length(xWerte)-1){
cuts <- c(cuts,xWerte[i+1])
}
cuts

# vals is supposed to contain the function rules in each interval
vals <- c()
for(i in 1:(length(xWerte)-1)){
# fi -> function rule in the i.th interval, also works fine...
fi <- function(x){
return(as.numeric(m[[i]])*x 
+(as.numeric(yWerte[i])
-as.numeric(m[[i]])*as.numeric(xWerte[i])))
}
# here, I want to add the i different function rules to the values
vals <- c(vals,fi)
}

# searchInt looks up the interval x is in, works fine
searchInt <- function(x){findInterval(x, c(0, cuts),rightmost.closed = TRUE)}
```

This all seems to do what I want it to do.
**Now, here's my problem:**

```
# fx should insert x to the function in vals 
# that belongs to the interval x is located in... 
fx <- function(x){vals[[searchInt(x)]](x)}
# one example with x= 0.8
print(fx(0.8))
```

This shows me

```
[1] 0.619
```

which is vals[length(vals)]=vals[6]. But as searchInt(0.8) = 5, it *should* show vals[5]=0.63806.

I know that I succeeded to add different function rules to vals, because if I do

```
for(i in 1:length(vals)){
print(vals[[i]](0.8))}
```

R shows me

```
[1] 0.15216
[1] 0.5143
[1] 0.5143
[1] 0.59998
[1] 0.63806 # this is vals[[5]](0.8), the result fx(0.8) should evaluate to...
[1] 0.619
```

So, the right function rules for the different intervals are there, but they cannot be called properly by fx.
It seems to me like R "forgot" that there used to be different function rules in vals. It just calls the last function rule added to vals, no matter what's the value of searchInt(x).

I've found out that this might be a problem of local and global variables, but I don't know how to fix it :(

Thankyou very much for reading and trying to help me!

P.S.: Sorry for faults. I'm not a native speaker but have tried my best ;)

Comment: You are essentially storing functions inside a list called `vals`, and your problem is that the wrong function is being called because `[searchInt(x)]` does not return the right index for `vals`. Put a `browser()` in the line in front of `fx <- function(x){vals[[searchInt(x)]](x)}`, then type `searchInt(x)` when you are in the browser to see if you are getting the right index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did what you suggested (at least I hope so...) and wrote browser(fx <- function(x){vals[[searchInt(x)]](x)}) and then searchInt(0.8), but this led to the right answer (5). searchInt(x) gets the right index from vals, but it seems that if I call vals from fx, R overrides every function in vals by the last one added.

Comment: So, I guess the problem is: R computes the fi's with the different values of i. But when I later call one of these functions, R only sees its dependence on i and than inserts the last known value of i. So, for example, if I compute fi for i = 1,...,5 every fi is stored as f5 and therefore also called as f5. But what I want R to do is to compute in every run of the for-loop fi with the current value for i and than save this function at vals[[i]] and call it exactly the way it is without referring to i again ... I hope you understand what I mean... is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you do `vals <-list()` instead of `vals <- c()`, then do `vals[[i]] <- fi` instead of `vals <- c(vals,fi)`. I don't quite understand your question. If the above doesn't work, try `fx <- function(x){vals[[searchInt(x)-1]](x)}` since you mention that your index is off by 1.

Comment: It makes no difference. The problem is not about serchInt. I try to show with a shorter example: `vals <- list()`
`for(i in 1:5){fi <- function(x){x*i}`
`vals[[i]] <- fi}` Then I call vals and get: `[[1]] function (x) {x * i}`

`[[2]]
function (x) {x * i}` etc where I needed [[1]] function(x) {x*1}, [[2]] function(x) {x*2} etc. So R does not understand that i is meant do define the function rule but not to be computed again when I call the function.

Comment: I finally found another question with the same problem, I think: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481404/how-to-create-a-vector-of-functions]. Unfortunately, I don't understand how to use it in my case because my function in vals should still be able to accept an argument x.