# Creating a matrix of functions in R - but get " attempt to apply non-function" when called

Tags: r, matrix

I've created a matrix of functions in R but when I call them x"row1","column1" I get the error "attempt to apply to non-function".  Just looking at the output with out the (), I see

```
function () 
{
    mycodehere
}

<environment: 0x00000000159a0790>
```

This would see to be a casting problem.  Do I need to cast this to a function or something?

I tried looking up how others define a matrix of functions and I have not seen anything resembling what I am doing.  Is this even possible?

Comment: See if this solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481404/how-to-create-a-vector-of-functions

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is simply a dimensioned atomic vector or list. You can't build a vector of functions, but you can build a list of functions. (Note: Attempting to build a vector of functions would automatically return a list of functions.)

When you have a "list matrix", you must use double-bracket indexing to access the content of a cell; single-bracket indexing simply returns another list with the indexed component as the sole component.

```
for (i in 1:6) assign(paste0('f',i),{ f <- function() x; body(f) <- i; f; },globalenv());
f1; f2; f3; f4; f5; f6; ## 6 simple functions
## function ()
## 1L
## function ()
## 2L
## function ()
## 3L
## function ()
## 4L
## function ()
## 5L
## function ()
## 6L
f1(); f2(); f3(); f4(); f5(); f6(); ## each returns an integer
## [1] 1
## [1] 2
## [1] 3
## [1] 4
## [1] 5
## [1] 6
m <- matrix(list(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6),3L,2L); ## build a dimensioned list of functions
m;
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,] ?    ?
## [2,] ?    ?
## [3,] ?    ?
m[3L,2L]; ## single-bracket indexing returns the list component
## [[1]]
## function ()
## 6L
##
m[3L,2L](); ## you can't "run" a list
## Error: attempt to apply non-function
m[[3L,2L]]; ## double-bracket indexing returns the list component value: the function
## function ()
## 6L
m[[3L,2L]](); ## run the function
## [1] 6
m[3L,2L][[1L]](); ## alternative
## [1] 6
```

Comment: Got it, I need the double bracket to return the actual function instead of a list. Thank you that was very helpful and apologies for the obvious newbie question.